# IOS-How to use corebluetooth into TWO view controller?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I want to use corebluetooth into two view controllers, first viewcontroller scan the device and show the list of the device on the iphone. Then, click the dynamic button that show the device you want to connect with, then the centralManager stop scan the peripheral and start to connect the peripheral in the second viewcontroller, and get the service and characteristic of the device. I could do this in the one view controller, and print out the information of the device. But I don't know how to do it into two view controllers.

I don't want to use any core data to print it out into second view controller.
I have read the link [iOS:Communicate from different view controllers using corebluetooth library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146105/ioscommunicate-from-different-view-controllers-using-corebluetooth-library), but can not solve my problem.

Comment: Use a Singleton that will manage the BLE communication part as said in the answer of the linked question.

Comment: Can you make an simple example to use the BLE in single class, for first view controller we use scan peripheral, the second view controller we use connect peripheral? TIA

Comment: It would be too broad. Learn what is a Singleton and how to create/use it. Then, with a concrete issue, you can come back.

Comment: Do we still need to redefine the corebluetooth in another class, and use it in other viewcontrollers? I think we already have the corebluetooth, right?